# .NET queued tasks (with async/await)

Tags: .net, async-await, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

I have a large number of tasks (~1000) that need to be executed. I am running on a 4-core processor, so I'd like to process 4 tasks at a time, in parallel.

To give you a starting point, here is some sample code.

```
class Program
{
    public class LongOperation
    {
        private static readonly Random RandomNumberGenerator = new Random(0);
        const int UpdateFrequencyMilliseconds = 100;

        public int CurrentProgress { get; set; }

        public int TargetProcess { get; set; }

        public LongOperation()
        {
            TargetProcess = RandomNumberGenerator.Next(
                (int)TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5).TotalMilliseconds / UpdateFrequencyMilliseconds, 
                (int)TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10).TotalMilliseconds / UpdateFrequencyMilliseconds);
        }

        public async Task Execute()
        {
            while (!IsCompleted)
            {
                await Task.Delay(UpdateFrequencyMilliseconds);
                CurrentProgress++;
            }
        }

        public bool IsCompleted => CurrentProgress >= TargetProcess;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
        {
            var operations = new List<LongOperation>();

            for(var x = 1; x <= 10; x++)
                operations.Add(new LongOperation());

            await ProcessOperations(4, operations);
        }).Wait();
    }

    public static async Task ProcessOperations(int maxSimultaneous, List<LongOperation> operations)
    {
        await Task.WhenAll(operations.Select(x => x.Execute()));
        // TODO: Process up to 4 operations at a time, until every operation is completed.
    }
}
```

I'd like some input on what classes I would use, and how I'd structure the `ProcessOperations` to process up to 4 operations at a time, until all operations are completed, in a single await-able `Task`.

I'm thinking of using a `SemaphoreSlim` object in some way, since it seems to be geared towards throttling a resource/process.

Comment: You should look in to [TPL DataFlow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603(v=vs.110).aspx) it is the library provided by microsoft for the exact situation you are trying to do. You would just need to replace your `List<LongOperation>` with a `ActionBlock<LongOperation>` and set the parallel limits.

Comment: I knew I was trying to invent a wheel, just didn't know where to find it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already been suggested, you need to use a handy [TPL Dataflow library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228609.aspx), with two blocks, for storing the messages before processing, and for actual action on them:

```
// storage
var operations = new BufferBlock<LongOperation>();
// no more than 4 actions at the time
var actions = new ActionBlock<LongOperation>(x => x.Execute(),
    new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4 });

// consume new operations automatically
operations.LinkTo(actions);
for(var x = 1; x <= 10; ++x)
{
    // blocking sending
    operations.Post(new LongOperation());
    // awaitable send for async operations
    // await operations.SendAsync(new LongOperation());
}
```

Also you can intriduce some throttling limits, like no more than 30 operations at the time, by settings the [`BoundedCapacity`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.dataflowblockoptions.boundedcapacity.aspx) option for your buffer.